# How do I store the response of a bash script ssh call instead of the call itself?

Tags: string, bash, ssh, awk

I'm performing data collection on about 150 RHEL servers through a script that gets copied (scp) out to each server, then run through ssh.  On the monitoring server, I have:

```
H="ssh cshoults@ /usr/local/sc/collect.sh $SENDER $OUTPUTMETHOD "
RESULT=`$H`;
echo $RESULT;
```

The script returns nine values separated by colons.  I'm then setting nine variables with something like this:

```
HST=`$H | awk -F' : ' '{ print $1}`
```

However, I can tell by the speed that it's going out to the remote server each time instead of going to the server once and setting the response to a string.  It's late in the day and I'm getting irritated by this one.  Can someone answer this for me?  If I say `HST=`$RESULT...`  it tries to execute the command and gives me command not found, so I know it's not right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to go to the server each time, save the result.

```
CMD="ssh cshoults@ /usr/local/sc/collect.sh $SENDER $OUTPUTMETHOD"
RESULT=$($CMD)
V1=$(echo $RESULT | awk -F ' : ' '{print $1}')
V2=...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an enhancement to Dietrich's response:

```
CMD="ssh cshoults@ /usr/local/sc/collect.sh $SENDER $OUTPUTMETHOD"
RESULT=$($CMD)
N=1
while [ $N -le 9 ]
do
    eval V$N=`echo $RESULT | cut -d: -f$N`
    N=`expr $N + 1`
done
```

Answer (score 0):

By the by, you can split into `$@` with a special form of `set`;

```
# Save current IFS
oldifs=$IFS
# Temporarily set up to split on colons
IFS=:
# Split $RESULT into $@
set -- $RESULT
# Restore IFS
IFS=$oldifs
# Result is now in $1 $2 $3 etc
```